# Different results from date_diff depending on the order of the dates

Tags: php, date

Has anyone else come ac across this strange situation ?

You can reproduce it using:

```
php -r 'print_r(date_diff(date_create("@1414783593"),date_create("@1417413436")));'
php -r 'print_r(date_diff(date_create("@1417413436"),date_create("@1414783593")));'
```

Comment: And what is the unexpected output?

Comment: @jww: the same output in both lines :)

Comment: @JonathanMolyneux: both lines return `30 days`, difference is only that one returns `1month 0day` and other `0month 30day`, which is basically the same, when we are talking about November. Why DateTime chooses for one or other, is beyond me.